# How to prove that Copy Constructor is mandatory

Tags: c++

I Have just created a class with an integer variable and a pointer variable. After creating its object , I passed it to a function. Even after returning the function the program is not throwing the exception

```
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;

class A
{

public :

    int i;

    char *c;

    void show();

};

void func(A obj);

int main()
{

    A a;

    a.i = 10;

    a.c = "string";

    cout << " Before Fun " << endl;

    a.show();

    cout << " Going To Call func " << endl;

    func(a);

    cout << " After func " << endl;

    a.show();

    return 0;

}


void A::show()
{
    cout << " The valuses in Object are " << i << '\t' << c  << endl;
}

void func(A aa)
{       
    cout << " The valuses in Object are " << aa.i << '\t' << aa.c  << endl;  
}
```

In The Func I am passing the object a (from main) and it would get copied in aa (stack of func). so after returning from the func if i call show ( the pointer c would be null of a), It would give me exception
But it is not happening . please help me to prove the requirement of copy constructor

Comment: A user-declared copy constructor isn't needed. Your class doesn't appear to need to do any resource management, perhaps you don't need a user-declared copy constructor?

Comment: `"the pointer c would be null of a"`. Why would you think that?

Comment: could you share the code for `func`.  I don't quite understand the prose.

Answer (score 7):

Hide the copy constructor. That will cause a compilation error everywhere it is called implicitly.

```
class A
{

public :

    int i;

    char *c;
private:
    A(const A& _other);
};
```

Comment: I have read the book, which says that in you have any pointer variable in the class, and you make a copy of that, the default copy constructor will copy member by member. So in this case the two pointers ( carter and createe) will point to same memory address. and once one go off that will delete the value at that location. and one second will try to access that value, The program crash.

Comment: @user2398729 Right, the member is a pointer. The pointer just holds a number which represents an address in memory. If that address is deleted in the destructor (or by any other means) and you try to de-reference it, then the program will crash.

Comment: @user2398729 The default copy constructor makes a shallow copy of the object, so it just copies the address that the member holds. It just increases the chance of an accidental de-reference. That by itself won't cause a crash.

Comment: but still I am not able to prove it via program. I need a program which can prove the statement

Comment: @user2398729 Like i told you, create a situation where  the memory pointed to by the member pointer is deleted. Then access the pointer in the object's copy.

Answer (score 1):

If no copy constructor is declared for an object, one is implicitly defined. This copy constructor copies each element of the object.

In your example, the call to `func(a)` will call this copy constructor, and so `aa` will be a copy of `a` (`aa.i` will be `10` and `aa.c` will point to the first element of `"string"`).

Comment: I have read the book, which says that in you have any pointer variable in the class, and you make a copy of that, the default copy constructor will copy member by member. So in this case the two pointers ( carter and createe) will point to same memory address. and once one go off that will delete the value at that location. and one second will try to access that value, The program crash. I just want to prove the same.

Comment: @user2398729: Yes, you make a copy of the pointer. It just happens that in the code in the question, the pointer is pointing to a string literal and so can never become invalid. Even if you did create an invalid pointer, the result would be undefined behaviour, which would not necessarily lead to a crash.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++11 you can do the following to remove the copy constructor

```
class A
{

public :

   int i;

   char *c;
   void operator=(const A& _other) = delete;
   A(const A& _other) = delete;
```

};

or even better:

```
class A : public NonCopyable   // perhaps std:: or if you prefer boost, boost::
{

public :

   int i;

   char *c;
};
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions

Answer (score 0):

An implicit copy constructor does exist if you do not define one explicitly. It is called in your `func()` function. `A` object is copied and assigned a value for its member `i`.

Result will be: that you do get with `show()` the value for `i` that you had before when calling `func`. This is with no surprise because you are not doing any assignment to members of A inside `A`.

Implicit copy constructor by the compiler provide member-wise copy. This is what you may need in most cases.

When is default constructor not sufficient ? you have pointer like members, and need a deep-copy of it. You don't want to copy the pointer (what copy constructor would do), but rather to have the object pointed to copied. But why do you need deep copy ? You don't want to copy the pointer (which is owned by any instance of the class), and end up calling twice destructor on the same pointer. From the second call to `delete` on this pointer, heap corruption ensues. You may also need copy constructor made explicit for shared_pointers.

Note that, for performance reasons, it is best pass object by const reference than by value.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the copy constructor provided by compiler is present.

Modify your code and write a copy constructor as:

```
//Default and copy constructor

A()
{
    i = 0;
    c = NULL;
}

A(const A& _other)
{
    cout<<"In copy cons"<<endl;
}
```

When you will modify the code as per above when **func** gets called then your own copy constructor gets called in this case you will get the junk values(can not predict) 
[image]

And if you modify your **copy constructor** code as

```
A(const A& _other)
{
    cout<<"In copy cons"<<endl;

    i = _other.i;

    c = new char [(strlen(_other.c) +1)];

    strcpy(c,_other.c);

}
```

[image]

Now you can see the differnce in both outputs and the use of Copy constructor how and where it's used.

Comment: I don't think that `new char (strlen(_other.c +1))` does what you think it does.

Comment: @CharlesBailey its just a good programming practice.To make deep copy other wise the copy will be shallow copy.So new char (strlen(_other.c +1)) present for deep copy.

Comment: You allocate a single char an initialize it with the value returned by `strlen` and then copy beyond the end of the allocated storage in every case except when `_other.c` has length 1 (note the difference between `strlen(s) + 1` and `strlen(s + 1)` as well).

Comment: yes. I have done that. but the thing is that, we have passed the object in the function the default copy constructor get called. which will do the member wise copy. In this case when control will return from the fun, the obj in that function will destroy, and will also delete the value pointed by the pointer. But in main the pointer in the object in the main function, will still be pointing to the same location which was cleared earlier by the object in func. Here if i try to print, due to null value my program must crash. But it is not happening.

Comment: the line should be **c = new char [(strlen(_other.c +1))];** my mistake

Comment: @user2398729 in copy constructor (my code) i am allocating the memory for coping object so there will be two different objects.

Comment: I still think that your code causes UB due to the `strlen(s + 1)` / `strlen(s) + 1` difference.

Comment: @CharlesBailey yes it is UB ...my intention was **c = new char [(strlen(_other.c) +1)];** only not c = new char [(strlen(_other.c +1))];  :) thanks to pointing out

Comment: @CharlesBailey and i was thinking you was asking why **new** is required so dint paid attention on my **syntax and the code line**

Answer (score 0):

When you make a class, a null constructor and copy constructor exist implicitly.
So that is why it does not throw an exception.
However, if you define ANY constructor, you will then need to define others otherwise the rest of the constructors will be  overwritten.
For example, you define a null constructor only. Then it will throw an exception. Because the implicitly defined copy constructor will be overridden.
This is one way of proving the need of a copy constructor.